# How to send "CTRL+C/SIGINT" to a remote host using Net::Ping in Perl?

Tags: perl, ping

How to send "CTRL+C/SIGINT" to a remote host using Net::Ping in Perl ? I'm looking for some function like : `Net::Ping->execute("CTRL+C"); or Net::Ping->echo("\x03");`

Comment: What would cause you to believe that `Net::Ping` would have such functionality?

Comment: Ctrl+C is something that you send from a terminal. `SIGINT` is something that you send to a process group. Neither are things that you can send via sockets which is what `Net::Ping` is for.

Comment: 100% Correct !  Actually the thing is [wired thing is]: When i ping to servers which are located across Geo [different sub net], am not able to ping it, however if i follow following manual approach I'm able to ping it": 1)Ping to the server 2)CTRL+c 3)Again Ping to the server, I'm able to ping :).! First I want to understand what SIGINT is exactly doing here & most important is if it's working then I need to automate this thing in my Perl script !

Comment: So the `CTRL-C` you're sending is not to the remote host but to the `ping` process you're running.  You could script something to send the first ping a SIGINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Net::Ping](http://search.cpan.org/~smpeters/Net-Ping-2.36/lib/Net/Ping.pm) doc tells you:

> This module contains methods to test the reachability of remote hosts on a network. A ping object is first created with optional parameters, a variable number of hosts may be pinged multiple times and then the connection is closed.

You cannot send any relecant data to the host.

And even when you could: What process "on the other side" should execute that "CTRL+C" thing? Would you expect my browser to react to it? Or some other random process?

And by react I mean: Read it as plain text input. But I think your intention is to terminate some process with a "Signal". Signals cannot be sent via network protocols, they are generated and distributed only inside one computer. You would have to invent your own protocol to bridge the gap.

Sorry, but your question is quite futile so far.